# Is it possible to DROP FILTER PREDICATE only if it exists?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm creating Row-Level Security in SQL server 2014.

It's possible to DROP FILTER PREDICATE on my table Client like this:

```
ALTER SECURITY POLICY rls.tenantAccessPolicy
    DROP FILTER PREDICATE ON dbo.Client,
    DROP BLOCK PREDICATE ON dbo.Client
GO
```

But if I execute this code twice in a row, I've got an error

> "The security policy 'rls.tenantAccessPolicy' does not contain a predicate on table 'dbo.Client'."

Is there a way to DROP it only if it exists?

Comment: Are you sure that you are using `SQL Server 2014` and not `SQL Server 2016`?

Comment: @lad2025 When I do "SELECT @@VERSION" I get "Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Aug 29 2017 13:06:11   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation" which seems to be a SQL Server 2014 from that website: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/321185/how-to-determine-the-version--edition-and-update-level-of-sql-server-a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution! I need to use dynamic SQL for this to work because the `SECURITY POLICY` keywords are executed before the `SELECT` or something which was causing my error.

This code only check if `filter` predicate is there, but since I'm always adding `filter` and `block` at the same time, the validation is fine with me:

```
IF EXISTS( SELECT 1
            FROM sys.security_predicates sp
            WHERE sp.predicate_type = 0 -- filter_predicate
                AND OBJECT_ID('rls.tenantAccessPolicy') = sp.object_id
                AND sp.target_object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.Client'))
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @Sql = N'ALTER SECURITY POLICY rls.tenantAccessPolicy
                DROP FILTER PREDICATE ON dbo.Client,
                DROP BLOCK PREDICATE ON dbo.Client'

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @Sql = N'ALTER SECURITY POLICY rls.tenantAccessPolicy
                ADD FILTER PREDICATE rls.fn_tenantAccessPredicateWithSuperUser(CompanyID) ON dbo.Client,
                ADD BLOCK PREDICATE rls.fn_tenantAccessPredicateWithSuperUser(CompanyID) ON dbo.Client'

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
END
GO
```

Comment: @lad2025 Thanks to your help! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 5):

I would use approach `IF EXISTS` and check [sys.security_predicates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-security-predicates-transact-sql) metadata table:

```
IF EXISTS( SELECT 1
           FROM sys.security_predicates sp
           WHERE sp.predicate_type = 0 -- filter_predicate
             AND OBJECT_ID('rls.tenantAccessPolicy') = sp.object_id
             AND sp.target_object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.Client'))
BEGIN    
    ALTER SECURITY POLICY rls.tenantAccessPolicy
        DROP FILTER PREDICATE ON dbo.Client; 
END;
GO

IF EXISTS( SELECT 1
           FROM sys.security_predicates sp
           WHERE sp.predicate_type = 1 -- block_predicate
             AND OBJECT_ID('rls.tenantAccessPolicy') = sp.object_id
             AND sp.target_object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.Client'))
BEGIN
    ALTER SECURITY POLICY rls.tenantAccessPolicy
        DROP BLOCK PREDICATE ON dbo.Client;    
END;
GO
```

Comment: I still get an error "The security policy 'rls.tenantAccessPolicy' does not contain a predicate on table 'dbo.Client'." when I run your first script (the one to remove the FILTER PREDICATE). I'll try te play with it a little to see if I can find a solution.

Comment: @pikarie I don't have access to SQL Server so I cannot check it. I suggest running **`SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id), OBJECT_NAME(target_object_id)  FROM sys.security_predicates)`** to match where conditions.

Comment: The variable are all correct. I added a SELECT 1 after the DROP, I created a ELSE statement and added a SELECT 2, and the crash occurs the second time I run in where my SELECT 1 is (which is weird because when I comment the ALTER, DROP, the result is "2" which means the code passes through the ELSE)

Comment: I also tried creating a StoredProcedure with the 2 lines ALTER and DROP, but I got the same error. It seems to be a problem with the SQL? It's like it is trying executing it even if I'm creating the StoredProc.